# List Categories of Custom Post Type without Category child

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, taxonomy

I have Created post_type=ug-dept and taxonomy=dept. Under the dept Taxonomy created some category and Subcategory. Added Post into that.

Now on listing Subcategory also Listed.

```
<ul>
  <?php wp_list_categories('taxonomy=dept&orderby=id&title_li=&include_children=false');?>
</ul>
```

How to Remove Child on Category Listing. Please don't give a solution like:
'exclude' => '12,13' By this every time i need to add.

Why "include_children=false" not working ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$cat_args = array(
    'taxonomy' => 'dept',
    'orderby' => 'id',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'parent' => 0,
);
$cat_data = get_categories( $cat_args ); 

foreach ( $cat_data as $cat ) {
      echo $cat->name;
}
```

It will help you